# Subroutine to format cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to format cells in excel

Following is the code I have:

```
Range("A1:F1").Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

I need to repeat the formatting steps multiple times for  different ranges, can I  call a subroutine instead?

Comment: I can give you a little hint: create new subroutin with this code (except first line - it should be slightly modified) and each time you need to use this code, call this new sub and pass desired range as parametr. This link could give you a good start: http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/functions/Lesson3.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to apply the format to a number of ranges in a loop:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    ary = Array(Range("A1:Z1"), Range("A3:Z3"), Range("A7:Z7"))
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        Call FFormat(ary(i))
    Next
End Sub

Sub FFormat(rIn As Variant)
    rIn.Font.Bold = True
    With rIn.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```